# How to gracefully shutdown Amazon ECS Fargate task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Problem: Fargate tasks are being shut down without completing the processes within the task upon scaling in. (Auto Scaling implemented)

Is there a possibility for the Fargate task to exit gracefully (to complete all the processes within the task before shutting it down)?

There is a way in EC2 to handle this through Life cycle hooks but I'm not sure if there is anything similar in the Amazon Fargate cluster.

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: When the task is shut down it does not complete all the jobs that are running within the task causing the jobs to be stuck in running state. Is there a way we can ignore the termination signal until all the jobs are completed. @RiteshKumarReddyKuchukulla

Comment: Can you describe the tasks you are trying to run?
And the reason why the ECS task is draning?

Answer (score 2):

In 2022 AWS introduced the [Task scale-in protection endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-scale-in-protection-endpoint.html).

```
The following task scale-in protection endpoint path is available to containers: $ECS_AGENT_URI/task-protection/v1/state
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but AFAIK Farage does not have ECS Agent - that's special to EC2 ECS and AWS often meshes up docs.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the `SIGTERM` signal and do your cleanup in there. You can trap it in your application, using whatever programming language that you want, or trap it in a shell entrypoint script.

For more information see [this blogpost from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/).